# Global variable is not showing result inside a ajax call

Tags: jquery

Here index is a global variable.
I am manipulating the index in another function.

after that I call this function.
its showing the actual result outside and after the ajax call but not showing inside the ajax call.

```
var urlSearch = "http://192.168.10.113/collective-intellegence/UserClickPersonClassifier?userid=1&query=asp.net";
alert(index);
$.ajax({
    url: urlSearch,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(index);
    }
});
```

Is there any mistake done by me.

Please help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is going to the success and showing alert message as 0.

Comment: And what is `index`?  Have you checked if it is not changed anywhere while your request is running?

Comment: yes it is not changing .
index is a global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the ajax request success. You can try adding an `alert('a');` before `alert(index);`

If it is entering in success, then you should make sure the function that handles `index` global variable doesn't fire after you make the ajax request and before you get the response. I'd add in that function an alert that says something like "Changed from XX to YY"

Comment: It is going to success.
already tested .
It is giving 0 but it should show 1

Comment: It is showing 1 If I write alert(index) before and after the ajax call.

and showing 0 inside the ajax call.

Comment: @bhagirathi That's because the callback fires when the AJAX request is done. In the mean time the rest of the code is executed.

Comment: To test if the variable is changed while waiting for a response add: 'async: false' to your options.

Comment: You can do what @bwicklund is saying or just add an alert where you change the variable.

Comment: Thanks a ton for reply 

yes its working fine if we do "async:false"

I think it will slower down my application.
Is there any other alternative to do this???

Comment: Yes.. but it is a manual work. You will have to track which part of your code is changing the value and think why it does it. Then analyze if that shouldn't be done or if it should be done after the ajax completes.